# React: cant get output inside a functional component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am having an `Array of objects` where I am trying to use `reduce` function to filter based on the keys of the object.
Here is the code for the whole project: [CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-boyd-dzbqt?file=/src/Exercises/index.js:269-295)

If you check the `index.js` file inside the `Exercises` Folder:

```
{exercices_.map(([category, array]) => {
          <Typography>{category}</Typography>;
})}
```

The `exercices_` is a nested array that inside each array I have the category and another array.
For now I am just trying to output the category but it's not working. The same code works in the `App.js` file when I use console. But when I am passing the array to the child Componenet It doesnt work anymore. You are free to change the code through the website but notice that you are the only one who sees these changes.

The expected output is just a string Like `Shoulders`. Make sure to check the console of the webpage since it has all the output there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning this  component on every iteration so it loops through it but the output array is empty.

A way to fix that:

```
{exercices_.map(([category, array]) => {
          return <Typography>{category}</Typography>;
})}
```

Check out how .map function works here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: wow, thanks man... I am new to JS..  I need to wait for 10 mins to accept your answer.

Comment: Also, I've forgot to tell you that you need to add key as mention in another answer when using loop for creating React Elements, as key is used for React to find out which element to update

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return, you also need to add a key when using an array of React elements

```
{exercices_.map(([category, array], index) => {
          return <Typography key={index}>{category}</Typography>;
})}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about the ```key``` but I was just trying to get some output for now. Thank you